# how to determine which button is pressed Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using velocityx Package
I am making the calculator similar to the iOS calculator.

```
import 'package:calculator/widgets/theme,.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:velocity_x/velocity_x.dart';


const Map labels = {
  "firstRow": ["AC", "+/-", "%", "÷"],
  "secondRow": ["7", "8", "9", "X"],
  "thirdRow": ["4", "5", "6", "-"],
  "fourthRow": ["1", "2", "3", "+"],
  "fifthRow": ["0", ".", "="],
};
```

The widget has four Rows, each row has four buttons (MyButton widget)

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        child: Scaffold(
            body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 180),
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                Screen(),
                MyButtons(
                  labels: labels["firstRow"],
                  c1: MyThemes.greyColor,
                  c2: MyThemes.yellowColor,
                ).pOnly(bottom: 20),
                MyButtons(
                  labels: labels["secondRow"],
                  c1: MyThemes.darkGreyColor,
                  c2: MyThemes.yellowColor,
                ).pOnly(bottom: 20),
                MyButtons(
                  labels: labels["thirdRow"],
                  c1: MyThemes.darkGreyColor,
                  c2: MyThemes.yellowColor,
                ).pOnly(bottom: 20),
                MyButtons(
                  labels: labels["fourthRow"],
                  c1: MyThemes.darkGreyColor,
                  c2: MyThemes.yellowColor,
                ).pOnly(bottom: 20),
                MyButtonsLastRow(
                    labels: labels["fifthRow"],
                    c1: MyThemes.darkGreyColor,
                    c2: MyThemes.yellowColor)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

MyButtons widget has 4 buttons in a row

```
class MyButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  final List labels;
  final Color c1;
  final Color c2;
  const MyButtons(
      {Key? key, required this.labels, required this.c1, required this.c2})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        MyB(label: labels[0], color: c1).pOnly(left: 10),
        MyB(label: labels[1], color: c1).pOnly(left: 10),
        MyB(label: labels[2], color: c1).pOnly(left: 10),
        MyB(label: labels[3], color: c2).pOnly(left: 10, right: 10),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This class for the last row which has only 3 buttons

```
class MyButtonsLastRow extends StatelessWidget {
  final List labels;
  final Color c1;
  final Color c2;
  const MyButtonsLastRow(
      {Key? key, required this.labels, required this.c1, required this.c2})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
              child:
                  "0".text.start.align(TextAlign.start).minFontSize(30).make()),
          style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(MyThemes.darkGreyColor),
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(StadiumBorder()),
            fixedSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size(170, 80)),
            // textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(),
          ),
        ).pOnly(left: 10),
        MyB(label: labels[1], color: c1).pOnly(left: 10),
        MyB(label: labels[2], color: c2).pOnly(left: 10, right: 10),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is single widget which all buttons are created from

```
class MyB extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final Color color;
  const MyB({Key? key, required this.label, required this.color})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
    
      },
      child: label.text.align(TextAlign.center).minFontSize(30).make(),
      style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(color),
          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(CircleBorder()),
          fixedSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size(80, 80))),
    );
  }
}
```

this is Screen where the result will be shown

```
class Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  const Screen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScreenState createState() => _ScreenState();
}

class _ScreenState extends State<Screen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return "0".text.xl6.align(TextAlign.end).make().pOnly(right: 30);
  }
}
```

Comment: on `MyButtons` create a callBack and based on and apply conditional state on `text`.

Answer (score 0):

`MyB` class holds the information about a button in the `label` property.

Try adding `print('$label pressed');` inside `onPressed` to verify this.

```dart
class MyB extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final Color color;
  const MyB({Key? key, required this.label, required this.color})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        print('$label pressed');
      },
      child: label.text.align(TextAlign.center).minFontSize(30).make(),
      style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(color),
          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(CircleBorder()),
          fixedSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size(80, 80))),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the standard way of doing this is as follow:

1. create a class for each button:

```
class MyButton{
String title;
int id;
int row;
int column;

MyButton(this.title, this.id, this.row, this.column);
}
```

so, you can the `row` and `column` parameters to produce calculator screen in a general widget. Also, you can use `id` to find out the selected button.

2. create a widget for each Button.

```
Widget MyButtonWidget(MyButton input){
ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
         print(input.id); /**/ YOU CAN PUT YOUR LOGIC HERE!!!!**
      },
      child: input.title.align(TextAlign.center).minFontSize(30).make(),
      style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(color),
          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(CircleBorder()),
          fixedSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size(80, 80))),
    );
}
```

3. then create a general widget for each row that takes a list of buttons and renders them (MyButtonWidget) by a GridView. for the last one create a specific one.

Comment: No need to create a new class. `MyB` already exists.

Comment: sure, just wanted to declare all steps!